# Use custom icon for google map in retina display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, retina-display

I use [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) for my application,
in this plugin we have `icon` option for `<marker>` :
http://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/docs/index.html

Now I have an icon and use in this option, but how can I say show `pin@2x.png` on retina displays ?

```
<map center="[40.74, -74.18]">
  <marker
      position="[40.76, -74.16]"
      draggable="false"
      visible="true"
      icon="pin.png"></marker>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Map API V3 there are two scale parameter for Custom Icon. One is size and other one is scaleSize. For this you can try out adding a scale parameter in the marker tag. This is a potential solution for getting a higher resolution while displaying the custom icons in Google Maps retina display.

```
<marker
  position="[40.76, -74.16]"
  draggable="false"
  visible="true"
  symbol="pin.png">
  scaleSize=2</marker>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

Hope this would help :)